# What kind of bike is this. Looking to buy it but not sure. Any help is appreciated

Tags: identify-this-bike

Was looking to buy bike. Does anyone have any idea what kind it is?

[image]

Comment: Yep, it's definitely a bike.  BMX.  Probably made in China.

Comment: Welcome to [SE] Wes. _The bike looks like a BMX bike to me._ It also has a rusty chain and seems to be in pitiful state. But perhaps you noticed that already yourself. Have a look at the [tour] to see what type of questions Stack Exchange may help you with.

Comment: a really cheap one, likely a made in china, department store/walmart bike

Comment: I notice the gutted remains of a left brake lever.  It has no brakes.  Therefore someone has removed parts for some reason.  The decals have all been removed to make identification harder too.

Comment: Finally, notice that IT'S GOT A *KICKSTAND*!   No BMXer in their right mind would consider riding a bike with a kickstand - that's just never done.

Answer (score 5):

It's a BMX of some kind. It's very unlikely that anyone will be able to identify it more precisely than that.

The fact that it has one-piece cranks (both cranks are formed from the same metal rod, which has two right-angles bent in it and is then inserted through the bottom bracket) implies that it's not a high-end bike. So, if the seller claims that it's something exciting, you should get them to prove that.

It also seems to be in rather bad condition: the grips are mangled, there's a broken-off brake lever. There are no brakes so this bike isn't legal to use on the street in most places.

Answer (score 2):

You're buying it?  Expect the seller to provide proof of provenance in the form of sales receipt, warranty, or similar paperwork.

Sadly there are many rogues out there who will claim it's an expensive BMX when it is not.  If the seller can't prove it, walk.